# Sharing WiFi connection (with a Usb Dongle) but limiting bandwidth

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking, network-shares

hope you can help me. 
I would like to share a cable Ethernet Internet Connection with.. the world. 
I've a cable router with an internet connection, and a pc, always powered on with Windows XP. 
I would like to use an "inutilized" WiFi Usb Dongle to trying to share my Internet Connection with everyone want to connect ... 
Obviously i want to "close" my internal network (my data, video etc.) and allow to the "world" to use Internet but... with a "small" bandwidth. 
I would like to share, 5-10% of my total bandwidth. 
So i ask you: does exists some software for Windows Xp to "throttle" the bandwidth for a particular network ? 
So i can "free" my master connection, and assign, 20-30-40 kbyte/s to the open and "shared" connectio.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to 100% secure your PC programatically, while sharing your internet connection.

The only really safe way to do this would be to get a switch and 2 routers, or an advanced firewall router that allows segregated networks, and have 2 networks with different subnets and ip schemas - one public and one private.

There may be a utility out there, but I wouldn't trust my PC to share a connection with ANY utility I found online.